# Test the beginning and the end of the input is not space

Tags: regex

I want to select those who doesn't begin or end with space.

Test String:

```
  ad 
bui sfa
daf
a
fa  
    12
```

Attempted Regex (with no match ;(... ):

```
^[^\s]*.*[^\s]*$
```

Here is the [link](https://www.regex101.com/r/qD4tX8/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex `^[^\s]*.*[^\s]*$` does not work because you applied `*` quantifier to the `[^\s]` negated character classes matching any symbol but whitespace, thus making this *optional*. Also, your input looks to be multiline, so in the online regex tester, you'd need to specify the `/m` multuline flag to see if the lines match your pattern. Also, the pattern **requires at least two** symbols to be present  in the input string, but you also have a `a` line (containing 1 symbol) - and it wouldn't get matched.

You can use

```
^(?!\s|.*\s$).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/tQ2fK8/1). Note the use of the `/m` multiline flag (necessary if your input is multiline). This pattern allows any string that does not begin or end with a whitespace.

A more detailed explanation:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!\s|.*\s$)` - a negative lookahead that fails a match if the string starts (due to the first `\s`) or (`|`) ends (due to `.*\s$`) with whitespace
- `.*$` - actually matches a line up to the end.

Comment: Ok I see why this is better than mine. Thanks for the lesson :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the regex: `^\S+(.*\S+)?$`.

- `\s` is a character class, that contains whitespaces. `\S` is the negated class. It stands for non-whitespaces.
- `^` matches at the beginning of a line.
- `^\S+` matches one or more non-whitspaces at the beginning of a line
- lets have a look at the second part: `(.*\S+)?` :

  - `.* means zero or more arbitrary chars
  - `\S+` is again one or more non-whitspaces
  - `(...)?` the question marks makes the part inside the parentheses optional. This makes the line `a` match.
- `$` means "at the end of a line".

Comment: Could you expain this as it would help others looking for same problem?

Comment: Clever idea. BTW, I'd remove `[]`, since the `\S` is a single pattern inside the character classes.

Comment: @stribizhev, @Codexer: I changed the answer regarding `[\S]` and added more details.